# What is "the plane" in graph theory?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition, planar-graphs

I have learnt that a planar graph is a graph which can be drawn on the plane without any of its edges crossing. What exactly is "the plane"? In plane geometry, we define a plane to be a flat surface of two dimensions; however here the use of "the" suggests we have a particular instance of a plane in mind, not just any plane. Is there a certain specific type of plane which is meant here, other than the general plane from plane geometry?

Comment: Anything homeomorphic to the Euclidean topology of $\Bbb R^2$ should do.

Comment: In this case "the plane" means a plane. It's more of an English expression than a mathematical one. Compare it to "I was in the hospital" in American English.

Comment: another simple consideration, graphs are graphically represented in a 2d world, the plane you use to draw it is the plane to consider (e.g. your piece of paper)

Comment: If a graph can be drawn on one plane (without any of its edges crossing), then it can be drawn on any other plane (with the same restrictions), so you can pick your favourite plane here